# Text continually scrolls across a screen

Tags: java, android

I am trying to figure out how to get a piece of text to continually scroll across a screen.

A game has a `top_score` and whilst the game is running I want to `top_score` to scroll across the bottom of the screen.

I presumed Scrollview would be what I need but I don't see anything that allows the text to automatically and continually scroll across the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add those lines to your `TextView`:

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

And in your JAVA:

```
TextView marque = findViewById(R.id.text_view_marque);
marque.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work, nothing moves. To add I have this TextView in a Linear layout, only the one Textview is in this layout. Willl this affect anything? Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise the text had to be wider than the width of the Textview for it to scroll. it works great now!